# How to use AddRange of ObservableValue in LiveCharts?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I want to use ObservableValue to draw a dynamic line. Because I have a lot of datas (1024 points in one package), according to the official document,I find this:

```
//Do Not
var cv = new ChartValues<double>();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    cv.Add(5);
}
```

```
//Instead Do
var temporalCv = new double[1000];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    temporalCv[i] = 5;
}

var cv = new ChartValues<double>();
cv.AddRange(temporalCv);
```

so I want to try similiar way.

I store my data in two lists:

```
list<double> xdata = new list<double>();
list<double> ydata = new list<double>();
```

I want to use AddRange to add 1024 poins at once to a dataValues:

```
 dataValues = new ChartValues<ObservableValue>
```

and delete the first 1024 points at onece when the length of xdata and ydata is more than 1024. But I dind't find similar function like removeRange.Besides I can't find anything about how to use AddRange of ObservableValue. Could you please tell me how to do? Thanks!

Comment: Please check all of the code in your question to make sure it is valid and compiles.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `.AddRange` for ChartValues. You have to create a new instance and pass the data, such as `dataValues = new ChartValues<ObservableValue>(yourDataList)`

Comment: @FCin Weird, I thought there was. https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Performance%20Tips

Comment: There is no RemoveRange, what it was supposed to do? AddRange is simple, you have `IEumerable<T>` and want to add all, but what you want `RemoveRange` to do?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use ChartValues<ObservableValue>.AddRange(IEnumerable<object>Items) or give me a sample code?  I could use AddRange to achieve the same goal instead of RemoveRange.